# Python data preprocessing: loading 10000 pictures from the same directory into one variable?

Tags: python

I got a dataset that has 10000 pictures, where each picture has a dimension of (64 * 64 * 3). 
I am able to load one picture with opencv2 like: `cv2.imread("dataset/1.png")`

How do I load all of the pictures into one variable so that the variable should have a dimension of (10000, 64, 64, 3).

Comment: Use a list, shove them into it. Should be about 10k*64*64*3 bytes ~ 120 MB or so

Comment: do you mean have one giant matrix which has sub matrixes of each image?

Comment: There are too many ways to approach this problem. The answers would just turn into a straw-poll for which one people liked. The best thing is to do some research on the topic yourself, find two or three, _analyze_ them, determine if they work for you or not, and _try them out_. Come to us when you have a specific question about something you have attempted to do. Please see the [ask] help page and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) blog post by Jon Skeet.

Comment: got it, I thought there was a high level command that takes care of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can stack your images together with `np.stack`.

```
import cv2
import glob
import numpy as np

images = list()

for image_path in glob.glob("/path/to/images/*.png"):
    image = cv2.imread(image_path)
    image = np.expand_dims(image, 3)

    images.append(image)

stacked_images = np.stack(images, 0)
```